# Classify the bifurcations that occur as $\mu$ is varied in $\dot\theta =u+\cos(\theta)+\cos(2 \theta)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Classify the bifurcations that occur as $\mu$  is varied $\dot\theta =\mu+\cos(\theta)+\cos(2 \theta)$

Im having trouble with this problem. This is as far as I have gotten:

I see how to use quadratic formula to solve for $\cos(\theta)=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{9-8\mu}}{4}$. Then the term under the square root becomes positive when $\mu=9/8 \iff \theta=\arccos(1/4)$.

I'm confused on how to solve for the other terms.

Comment: There are more than one values of $\mu$ for which the number of equilibria changes. These are your only bifurcation values when you are dealing with 1d autonomous systems.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start. You can use [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html), e.g.

```
f[m_, t_] := m + Cos[t] + Cos[2 t]
(* the "critical points" *)
pt[m_] := t /. Quiet[Solve[f[m, t] == 0 && 0 < t < 2 Pi, t]] 
(* solving numerically *)
nds = t /. 
   ParametricNDSolve[{t'[u] == f[m, t[u]], t[0] == t0}, {t}, {u, 0, 
     10}, {t0, m}];
(* visualizing *)
Manipulate[
 Show[StreamPlot[{1, f[m, t]}, {u, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
  Plot[Evaluate[nds[t0, m][u]], {u, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> Full], GridLines -> {None, pt[m]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> {Purple, Thickness[0.01]}], {m, -1, 1}, {{t0, Pi},
   0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that helps a lot. Do you know how to calculated it without refering to technology? Im confused on what to look for. All the other problems I have done have been straight forward about what the points were

Comment: @thisguy I am not sure I understand your comment.  Was your question intended for the Math stackexchange rather than Mathematica stackexchange? The function `pt` above finds the values of $\theta'(t)=0$